# Internet Explorer innerHTML "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: javascript

I have a script that checks the value of a Div Id.

```
   <div id="hour" style="display:none;">2</div>
   <div id="min" style="display:none;">1</div>
   <div id="sec" style="display:none;">3</div>

   hour = document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML;
   min = document.getElementById("min").innerHTML;
   sec = document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML;
```

Works in Chrome, but not in Internet Explorer (Which is where I need it to work)

It gives me the error, "Object doesn't support this property or method"

What is the easier way (preferably one line) to get around this?

Comment: Which version of IE?  Works fine for me in IE9.  http://jsfiddle.net/m6SvE/

Comment: don't use innerHTML. Check out [this question!!][1] 

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267245/how-to-get-value-of-h2-tag-for-a-div-inside-other-div-with-id-using-javascript/8293161#8293161

Comment: don't use innerHTML. Check out [this question!!][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267245/how-to-get-value-of-h2-tag-for-a-div-inside-other-div-with-id-using-javascript/8293161#8293161

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're naming variables with the same name as DOM elements.  I seem to recall IE treating dom elements as first-class citizens, so this may be the cause of your problem.

Try:

```
var hourHtml = document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML;
var minHtml = document.getElementById("min").innerHTML;
var secHtml = document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML;
```

Comment: This can also happen if you use a variable name that exists higher up on your page.

Answer (score 0):

don't use innerHTML. Apparently its microsoft proprietary function and so not in DOM Standard...

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267245/how-to-get-value-of-h2-tag-for-a-div-inside-other-div-with-id-using-javascript/8293161#8293161)