# c# How to grab string from inside <b> that's inside a div class

Tags: c#

So I have been using things like this:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("month").SetAttribute("value", exp1);
```

Which allows me to set values, but now I want to grab a value instead of replacing it.

```
<div class="contents">
<div class="background">stuff</div>
<div class="content">
<h2>title</h2>
<p>
Blah blah number is <b>0100000</b>
<p>
</div>
</div>
```

How can I grab the number inside the  tag that's inside the content class? Kind of stuck!

Thanks!

Comment: webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("month").val()

Comment: @idipous I think he wants the value inside the <b> element, not the entire value inside the month container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the code you need:

```
string theText;
foreach (HtmlElement item in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
        {
            if (item.GetAttribute("className") == "content")
                theText = item.GetElementsByTagName("b")[0].InnerText;
        }
```

Comment: webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div").Cast<HtmlElement>().Where(p => p.GetAttribute("className") == "content").First().GetElementsByTagName("b")[0].InnerText

Comment: @VaughanSlaterit No, it works on the html you provided in the question

Comment: Sorry, I missed a few things (because I'm stupid) in the html. I updated the question with the full html.. Would that be why it's not working for me? Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can always get `InnerText` or `InnerHtml` of a chosen tag.
Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2958449/1786034

Comment: I'm looking to get the value from the <b> from inside a class though and not and ID. I've tried the ones in the questions but no luck..

Comment: You said that you don't know how to get a content of a tag. That is a correct answer for your question. But it turns out that you don't know how to get `<b>` tag either. For this you need `GetElementsByTagName("b")[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267245/how-to-get-value-of-h2-tag-for-a-div-inside-other-div-with-id-using-javascript)

```
document.getElementById('id').getElementsByTagName('b').firstChild.nodeValue
```